# What's the order among null columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my rails 3 application, there is a model called `Book`,

```
Book(id: integer, link_index: integer, publish_status: integer, link_page: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

`link_index` **is allowed to be `NULL`**, and others are not allowed to be NULL,  when I query like this:

```
Book.where(link_page: 1).published.order('link_index DESC').limit(5).pluck(:id)
```

it returns `[518, 331, 486, 488, 493]`.

but when I use `map` instead of `pluck`,

```
Book.where(link_page: 1).published.order('link_index DESC').limit(5).map(&:id)
```

it returns `[518, 512, 516, 534, 566]`.

All we know is that: only the column where id = 518 has link_index = 4, all other columns' link_index IS NULL. So the result is right: 518 is returned as the first element.

**But in above two ways, why the order among NULL elements is different?**

---

**UPDATED:**

Maybe it's not about `map` and `pluck`, because I use SQL directly in mysql shell, it's always the same issue:

```
SELECT id FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`link_page` = 1 AND `books`.`publish_status` = 4 ORDER BY link_index DESC LIMIT 5;
```

returns:

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 518 |
| 331 |
| 486 |
| 488 |
| 493 |
+-----+
```

But

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`link_page` = 1 AND `books`.`publish_status` = 4 ORDER BY link_index DESC LIMIT 5;
```

returns:

```
+-----+------------+----------------+-----------+
| id  | link_index | publish_status | link_page |  
+-----+------------+----------------+-----------+
| 518 |          4 |              4 |         1 |
| 512 |       NULL |              4 |         1 |
| 516 |       NULL |              4 |         1 |
| 534 |       NULL |              4 |         1 |
| 566 |       NULL |              4 |         1 |
+-----+------------+----------------+-----------+
```

**WHY?**

Comment: your `map` version always producing the same result ?

Comment: yes! always the same.

Answer (score 0):

map and pluck are completely different functions. **map** runs on the collection level  where as **pluck** runs on db level.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

Comment: Thanks~ I know the difference between `map` and `pluck`, but maybe the issue is not caused by this, see I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check [MySQL EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) of those two. The difference will be in index used to retrieve the data or in usage of some temp table. First query returns only ID, so index scan or index merge on proper indexes can be used to get those IDs and then order depends on BTREE ordering of those. In case of the second one, plan will be different, using maybe different set of indexes or different order of them, so it picks row in other order - and if lot of values is NULL, then no "right" order exists (you did not define second column to be used in case of duplicate link_index) and mysql is free to pick what it finds best (least costly plan and other stuff hides in there).